Reducing base64 image in React JS
I am creating a pdf by including base64 images into PDf, by my pdf size is very big due to multiple images. is there any way to reduce the image size. i dont have any control over original image size as it is been downloaded from external source. Can we reduce the base64 size and use it in React JS (Java script).
I tried to set the height and width to lower value, but that also not working.
